# Get escaped URL parameter

Tags: javascript, url, query-string, url-parameters

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin that can get URL parameters, and support this search string without outputting the JavaScript error: "malformed URI sequence". If there isn't a jQuery plugin that supports this, I need to know how to modify it to support this.

```
?search=%E6%F8%E5
```

The value of the URL parameter, when decoded, should be:

```
æøå
```

(the characters are Norwegian).

I don't have access to the server, so I can't modify anything on it.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-with-jquery/901144#901144

Comment: The reason that you are getting "malformed URI sequence" is because the majority of functions use `decodeURIComponent()`.  The Norwegian characters were most likely encoded using something like `escape()` and changing the `decodeURIComponent()` call to an `unescape()` should help.

Comment: See my answer for a modern solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19992436/64949

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should not use jQuery for something like this!**
The modern way is to use small reusable modules through a package-manager like Bower.

I've created a tiny [module](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string) that can parse the query string into an object. Use it like this:

```
// parse the query string into an object and get the property
queryString.parse(unescape(location.search)).search;
//=> æøå
```

Comment: If you're saying it's not modern to have a framework, that's fine. But in my opinion frameworks really do have their place. jQuery is looking less and less pretty to me though.

Answer (score 418):

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

Comment: With `name = 'bar'`, I think this regexp would match `'foobar=10'` and return `'10'`. Maybe you could add `'[?|&]'` at the beginning of your regexp. Cheers!

Comment: this function returns 'null' instead of null when the parameter is not defined... the joy of js...

Comment: you may want "decodeURIComponent()" instead of "decodeURI()", especially if you are passing interesting data like return URLs in as a URL parameter

Comment: This is good, but decodeURIComponent is better, for example I had a hashtag (%23) in my param that would be ignored by decodeURI. And I would not return null, but "", because decodeURI(null) === "null", which is a weird return value, "" is better; you can do if (!getURLParameter("param")) instead of if (getURLParameter("param") === "null"). So, my improved version: decodeURIComponent( (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1] )

Comment: **This fixes 'null' instead of null issue:**                       function getURLParameter(name) {
     var param = (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1];
   return (param?:decodeURI(param):param);
   }
}

Comment: Down voted as this returns string no matter if the result was found or not, and no matter what you put as alternative array e.g.[,null], because thre result was wrapped within decodeURI which turned anything into string, Sanjeev was right but his code wasnt tested correctly and simple copy and paste doesnt work. `function getURLParameter(name) {
    var p = RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search);
    
    if(!!p)
    {
        p = decodeURI(p[1]);
    }
    return p;
    
}`

Comment: This does'nt seem to work with URL : 'http://localhost:8888/?version=fghdfghd' , this accepted answer does : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter/979995#979995

Comment: If anyone is trying to get rid of the JSLint error on this, Just change [,null] into [undefined, null]

Comment: This returns string 'null' instead of real null. This is absolutely fatal in shorthand conditions like `if (getUrlParameter('test'))`. That will ALWAYS pass. Solution from @radicand is better.

Answer (score 294):

Below is what I have created from the comments here, as well as fixing bugs not mentioned (such as actually returning null, and not 'null'):

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null;
}
```

Comment: How about adding `new` in front of RegExp? Less lint warnings.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Getting real null back instead of "null" is way better.

Comment: If anyone needs this converted to coffeescript:
    getURLParameter: (name) ->
      return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp("[?|&]#{name}=([^&;]+?)(&|##|;|$)").exec(location.search) || [null,""] )[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null;

Comment: you don't need to use return in coffeescript... why does everyone keep doing that

Comment: For parameters that aren't followed by equals sign, which is perfectly legal, this will return null. Example, `?a=1&b&c`.  You might want to return empty string for c, and undefined for something that isn't there at all for example d.  I end up using `function getParam(param) {
  var query = new RegExp('[?|&]'+param+'(=)?(.*?)(&|#|$)');
  var search = document.URL.match(query);
  if (search){
    return decodeURIComponent(search[2]);
  }
}
`

Comment: @Redbeard - Shouldn't your function have a '=' sign after method definition instead of a double colon?

Comment: @radicand doesn't work (chrome latest) - http://jsfiddle.net/orwellophile/4JhHA/  just returns null

Comment: @Orwellophile, it does work, your test code is bad (location.search is a string of the latter half of the URL bar, whereas your code should just use "_location").  See http://jsfiddle.net/drWKu/

Comment: Ahh, indeed. My bad. Well, good to have a fiddle, and good to have a version that can operate on (optional) URLs other than current location.

Comment: This works much better than the above solution in my testing.

Comment: my code was breaking when there was no location.search, I am using `return (location.search.length?decodeURIComponent((new RegExp("[?|&]"+str+"=([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)").exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g,"%20")):"");`

Comment: This is the only version of a get-URL-parameter function that works for me with a UTF8 string.

Answer (score 107):

What you really want is the [jQuery URL Parser plugin](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser). With this plugin, getting the value of a specific URL parameter (for the current URL) looks like this:

```
$.url().param('foo');
```

If you want an object with parameter names as keys and parameter values as values, you'd just call `param()` without an argument, like this:

```
$.url().param();
```

This library also works with other urls, not just the current one:

```
$.url('http://allmarkedup.com?sky=blue&grass=green').param();
$('#myElement').url().param(); // works with elements that have 'src', 'href' or 'action' attributes
```

Since this is an entire URL parsing library, you can also get other information from the URL, like the port specified, or the path, protocol etc:

```
var url = $.url('http://allmarkedup.com/folder/dir/index.html?item=value');
url.attr('protocol'); // returns 'http'
url.attr('path'); // returns '/folder/dir/index.html'
```

It has other features as well, check out its [homepage](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser) for more docs and examples.

Instead of writing your own URI parser for this specific purpose that *kinda* works in *most* cases, use an actual URI parser. Depending on the answer, code from other answers can return `'null'` instead of `null`, doesn't work with empty parameters (`?foo=&bar=x`), can't parse and return all parameters at once, repeats the work if you repeatedly query the URL for parameters etc.

Use an actual URI parser, don't invent your own.

For those averse to jQuery, there's [a version of the plugin that's pure JS](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser/tree/no-jquery).

Comment: The question is "get URL parameter with jQuery". My answer answers the question. Other answers instruct the user to basically write his own URI parser for this specific use case, which is a terrible idea. Parsing URI's is more complicated that people think.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, and is very jQuery-ish, unlike some of the other answers.

Comment: Does the plugin handles the URI encoding or do I have to decode it manually?

Comment: The question says "javascript" (I think it means the DOM directly) or jQuery. So any of the others will do.

Answer (score 43):

If you don't know what the URL parameters will be and want to get an object with the keys and values that are in the parameters, you can use this:

```
function getParameters() {
  var searchString = window.location.search.substring(1),
      params = searchString.split("&"),
      hash = {};

  if (searchString == "") return {};
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var val = params[i].split("=");
    hash[unescape(val[0])] = unescape(val[1]);
  }
  return hash;
}
```

Calling getParameters() with a url like `/posts?date=9/10/11&author=nilbus` would return:

```
{
  date:   '9/10/11',
  author: 'nilbus'
}
```

I won't include the code here since it's even farther away from the question, but weareon.net posted a library that allows manipulation of the parameters in the URL too:

- Blog post: http://blog.weareon.net/working-with-url-parameters-in-javascript/
- Code: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1163515/

Comment: Yes, this is better to obtain all the params. All the other solutions listed here repeat the regex for each param.

Comment: This function returns an awkward object: `{"": undefined}` when the URL is void of parameters. Best to return an empty object by using `if(searchString=='') return {};` directly after the `searchString` assignment.

Answer (score 40):

You can use the browser native [location.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) property:

```
function getParameter(paramName) {
  var searchString = window.location.search.substring(1),
      i, val, params = searchString.split("&");

  for (i=0;i<params.length;i++) {
    val = params[i].split("=");
    if (val[0] == paramName) {
      return unescape(val[1]);
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

But there are some jQuery plugins that can help you:

- [query-object](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object)
- [getURLParam](http://www.mathias-bank.de/2007/04/21/jquery-plugin-geturlparam-version-2/)

Comment: This is much cleaner and more readable (and probably more bug-free) than all those regex one-liners.

Comment: I'll suggest to use decodeURIComponent() instead of unescape()

Comment: +1 this works for modern browsers but some devs need to work with... :| IE8 :S.

Answer (score 25):

Based on the [999's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1404100/244297):

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent(
        (location.search.match(RegExp("[?|&]"+name+'=(.+?)(&|$)'))||[,null])[1]
    );  
}
```

Changes:

- `decodeURI()` is replaced with `decodeURIComponent()`
- `[?|&]` is added at the beginning of the regexp

Comment: Might be helpful for others if you could explain why you made these changes. Thx

Comment: Doesn't handle empty params: `?a=&b=1`. Better regexp would be: `"[?&]"+name+"=([^&]*)"`

Answer (score 6):

Need to add the i parameter to make it case insensitive:

```
  function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent(
      (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)', 'i').exec(location.search) || [, ""])[1]
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

After reading all of the answers I ended up with this version with + a second function to use parameters as flags

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)','i').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null;
}

function isSetURLParameter(name) {
    return (new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '(?:[=|&|#|;|]|$)','i').exec(location.search) !== null)
}
```

Comment: Good Answer, just one warning however. Per JSHint, [,""] can cause issues for older browsers.  So, use instead [null,""] or [undefined,""].  There are still some of us unhappy few who support IE8 and dare I say it IE7.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
  var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(top.window.location.href); 
  return (results !== null) ? results[1] : 0;
}

$.urlParam("key");
```

Answer (score 2):

For example , a function which returns value of any parameters variable.

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}​
```

And this is how you can use this function assuming the URL is,

**"http://example.com/?technology=jquery&blog=jquerybyexample".**

```
var tech = GetURLParameter('technology');
var blog = GetURLParameter('blog');
```

So in above code variable "tech" will have "jQuery" as value and "blog" variable's will be "jquerybyexample".

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of buggy code here and regex solutions are very slow. I found a solution that works up to 20x faster than the regex counterpart and is elegantly simple:

```
    /*
    *   @param      string      parameter to return the value of.
    *   @return     string      value of chosen parameter, if found.
    */
    function get_param(return_this)
    {
        return_this = return_this.replace(/\?/ig, "").replace(/=/ig, ""); // Globally replace illegal chars.

        var url = window.location.href;                                   // Get the URL.
        var parameters = url.substring(url.indexOf("?") + 1).split("&");  // Split by "param=value".
        var params = [];                                                  // Array to store individual values.

        for(var i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++)
            if(parameters[i].search(return_this + "=") != -1)
                return parameters[i].substring(parameters[i].indexOf("=") + 1).split("+");

        return "Parameter not found";
    }

console.log(get_param("parameterName"));
```

Regex is not the be-all and end-all solution, for this type of problem simple string manipulation can work a huge amount more efficiently. [Code source](http://www.texodigital.com/blog/JavaScript/javascript-url-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getURLParameter(name) {
        return decodeURIComponent(
            (location.search.toLowerCase().match(RegExp("[?|&]" + name + '=(.+?)(&|$)')) || [, null])[1]
        );
    }

</script>
```

`getURLParameter(id)` or `getURLParameter(Id)` Works the same : )

Answer (score 0):

jQuery code snippet to get the dynamic variables stored in the url as parameters and store them as JavaScript variables ready for use with your scripts:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
       return null;
    }
    else{
       return results[1] || 0;
    }
}

example.com?param1=name&param2=&id=6

$.urlParam('param1'); // name
$.urlParam('id');        // 6
$.urlParam('param2');   // null

//example params with spaces
http://www.jquery4u.com?city=Gold Coast
console.log($.urlParam('city'));  
//output: Gold%20Coast

console.log(decodeURIComponent($.urlParam('city'))); 
//output: Gold Coast
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function getURLParameters(paramName) 
{
        var sURL = window.document.URL.toString();  
    if (sURL.indexOf("?") > 0)
    {
       var arrParams = sURL.split("?");         
       var arrURLParams = arrParams[1].split("&");      
       var arrParamNames = new Array(arrURLParams.length);
       var arrParamValues = new Array(arrURLParams.length);     
       var i = 0;
       for (i=0;i<arrURLParams.length;i++)
       {
        var sParam =  arrURLParams[i].split("=");
        arrParamNames[i] = sParam[0];
        if (sParam[1] != "")
            arrParamValues[i] = unescape(sParam[1]);
        else
            arrParamValues[i] = "No Value";
       }

       for (i=0;i<arrURLParams.length;i++)
       {
                if(arrParamNames[i] == paramName){
            //alert("Param:"+arrParamValues[i]);
                return arrParamValues[i];
             }
       }
       return "No Parameters Found";
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I created a simple function to get URL parameter in JavaScript from a URL like this:

```
.....58e/web/viewer.html?page=*17*&getinfo=33


function buildLinkb(param) {
    var val = document.URL;
    var url = val.substr(val.indexOf(param))  
    var n=parseInt(url.replace(param+"=",""));
    alert(n+1); 
}
buildLinkb("page");
```

OUTPUT: `18`

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11808489/419

Answer (score -1):

Just in case you guys have the url like  localhost/index.xsp?a=1#something and you need to get the param not the hash.

```
var vars = [], hash, anchor;
var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
if(q != undefined){
    q = q.split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
        hash = q[i].split('=');
        anchor = hash[1].split('#');
        vars.push(anchor[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = anchor[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Slight modification to the answer by @pauloppenheim , as it will not properly handle parameter names which can be a part of other parameter names.

Eg: If you have "appenv" & "env" parameters, redeaing the value for "env" can pick-up "appenv" value.

Fix:

```
var urlParamVal = function (name) {
    var result = RegExp("(&|\\?)" + name + "=(.+?)(&|$)").exec(location.search);
    return result ? decodeURIComponent(result[2]) : "";
};
```

Answer (score -2):

This may help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert(getParameterByName("third"));
    });
    function getParameterByName(name){
        var url     = document.URL,
            count   = url.indexOf(name);
            sub     = url.substring(count);
            amper   = sub.indexOf("&"); 

        if(amper == "-1"){
            var param = sub.split("=");
            return param[1];
        }else{
            var param = sub.substr(0,amper).split("=");
            return param[1];
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: This code is not tested well. Guess what happens with query `?twothrids=text`