# JavaScript: get and set variables in window.location.hash?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone have a good solution for getting and setting variables in `window.location.hash`?

Take a URL that looks like this:

```
domain.com/#q=1&s=2
```

What I'd like is an unstressful way - JavaScript or jQuery -  to check the values of `q` and `s` when the page loads, and change them following events on the page.

I have found [some code for getting hash variables](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html), but nothing sensible for setting them.

Am I missing something really obvious, or do I need to roll my own solution (and release it!)?

Thanks.

Comment: I can write my own regex if needed - just wondering if there was a tidier way.

Comment: With regex, setting/getting is one line of code. That's the simplest method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) can do this.

See also:

- [Get URL parameter with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery)
- [Get QueryString values with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery)

---

***Edit*** as [@gonchuki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387002/gonchuki) points out, [jQuery.query](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) can also do this.

Comment: jquery.url.js doesn't support hash params, or so it seems, alas.

Comment: ... and jQuery URL parser only gets the total value of the anchor, not parameters within it.

Comment: @AP257: then you probably want jQuery BBQ.

Comment: Yes, BBQ looks like the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: @gonchuki: you're right, thanks! I'll edit that in to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't used it but there is [jHash](http://jhash.codeplex.com/)

> jHash allows you to work with the
>   'location.hash' value in a similar
>   fashion to a server-side query string.
>
> This library utilizes the HTML5
>   "onhashchange" event, but also
>   includes a fall back to still allow
>   the change notifications to work
>   properly in older web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

JHash didn't work for me in that I wanted it to trigger the routes right away.  I personally used [routie](http://projects.jga.me/routie/#toc1) instead.

It lets you do advanced routing just like jHash but will trigger on page load correctly.

Below will match `example.com/#users/john`

```
routie('users/:name', function(name) {
    //name == 'bob';
});
```