# Get Parameter from DHTMLWindow

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

I have an HTML web page that openes a DHTMLWindow, and I want to send that window a parameter
from the 'fater' HTML web page, so the DHTMLWindow would be able to pass it on to one of it's 'son' windows.

How can I send parameter to DHTMLWindow?

Or, maybe, is there a way to replace that DHTMLWindow with regualar popup window openened with window.open command?

Really need your help,
Tal.

Comment: The meaning of 'fater' is parent ? And 'son' is child ?

Comment: What I mean is, that now, from the HTML page I built, when I press Ctrl+Alt+D, the DHTMLWindow will be opened, and on that DHTMLWindow, there are few buttons, that opens regular pop up windows. I want, if poosible, to transfer parameter from the first HTML page that I built, to the DHTMLWindow, and from him to the popup windows that can be opened from him.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand, does the DHTMLWindow is the new tab page ?

Comment: no, it's not opened as a new tab but like a popup window

Comment: I need an answer whether I can send parameters from URL to standard DHTMLWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.opener` to access the parent page.

***First,*** create function at first page to pass parameter to child page like this.

**Mainpage.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sentParam()
{
    return "param receive";
}
</script>
```

and the child page

**ChildPage.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var paramGet = window.opener.sentParam();
    alert(paramGet);
</script>
```

Comment: I i'm trying to alert window.opener in the HTML opened by the DHTMLWindow but i'm getting the value 'undefined'

Comment: so I need to know if I can open a DHTMLWindow with URL parameters?

Comment: I need an answer whether I can send parameters from URL to standard DHTMLWindow

Comment: if you want to pass parameter by url, it's alright. Put `?` at the end of url and insert parameter then. _Example_ `www.mysite.com/index.html?param=xxx&param2=yyy&param3=aaa`

Comment: And this is [how to get parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery)