# Getting URL parameter from Jquery mobile UI

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-dialog

How do i get the URL for the dialog( using jquery mobile UI which is a .jsp page with elements).I am passing parameters to the dialog as xyz.com?id=123&url=dlfwlfjwejpfwjfef;

So i want to  get this in my dialog box how do i go ahead can anyone help?

Comment: could you please post the relevant code over here so that we may better guide?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1404100/190695

Comment: if you're still struggling with this, I created a [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) which may help.