# auto checkbox based from url value using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkboxlist

Is there way to or it is possible to do it using javascript/jQuery?

Based Link URL: first one will check Type A and Type B and second example will check Type D

```
?type=A&type=C or ?type=D
```

My current form:

```
<form name="input" action="" method="post" ><br />
Select Type: <br />
<input type="checkbox" name = "type" value="A" /> A <br />
<input type="checkbox" name = "type" value="B"  /> B <br />
<input type="checkbox" name = "type" value="C"  /> C <br />
<input type="checkbox" name = "type" value="D" /> D <br /> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Any tips and advised to do it?

Comment: you'll need server generated page to do that...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
var i = document.location.href.lastIndexOf('?');
var types = document.location.href.substr(i+1).replace(/type=/g,'').split('&');
$('input[name="type"]').prop('checked',function(){
     return $.inArray(this.value,types) !== -1;
});
```

*Explanation*:

Consider the url is '`http://sample.com?type=A&type=C`'. Then:

- `i` is the index of '`?`' sign in that url
- [**.substr()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) will cut `type=A&type=C` part from the url. After the cut, we will have this string:

  ```
  "type=A&type=C"
  ```
- [**.replace()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) removes "type=" parts from the above mentioned string:

  ```
  "A&C"   //after replace
  ```
- [**.split()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) splits that string into array:

  ```
   ["A","C"]
  ```
- [**$.inArray()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) checks whether value of current `checkbox` is in the `["A","C"]` array. If it is, then `checks`( `.prop('checked',true)` ) the `checkbox`.

Comment: With the `search` of the `window.location` containing only `type=A&type=C`, boxes A, B, and C return as checked with your code.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy That's right. I have just forgotten about such property )

Comment: I've tested your code and it doesn't work as intended. I tried it in a local environment, using `http://localhost/dev/so/index.php?type=A&type=C`, and it checks boxes `B, C, and D`. I was able to reproduce this in a jsFiddle by mimicing the location of the window as a string, and testing your code against that. [Here's the jsFiddle. What's the issue?](http://jsfiddle.net/S6yGw/1/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I have updated my code, added ` !==-1 ` after the `inArray`

Comment: @noviceRick his code **will** work with your form, [and I've made a jFiddle for proof.](http://jsfiddle.net/S6yGw/2/)

Comment: @noviceRick Check again,we were talking with `OhGodWhy` about one little issue, that I have resolved a minute ago.

Comment: @Engineer and Ohgodwhy, I tested it now works perfectly, Explanation are clear to me too +1

Comment: @Engineer one last thing about the checkbox with white space value, I just wonder if this anyone have this situation e.g : ?type=A+B&type=C+D

Comment: @noviceRick In that case, you can replace `+` symbols, with `space`. add something like this between `replace` and `split`: `.replace(/type=/g,'').replace(/+/g,' ').split(`, or apply `decodeURI` function to `?type=A+B&type=C+D` string.

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter) shows a solution to check the query string parameters using javascript. There is also a link at the top to a possible [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery) that provides a solution using JQuery.

Once you determine the querty string parameters, you can use jQuery to check the box (as detailed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)):

```
$('input[value="A"]').prop("checked", true);
```