# Match url in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get URL parameter with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery)

I got this url in my browser

```
http://docs.google.com?k=account&cs=This%20Site&u=https%3A%2F%2Faccess.dev.google.com
```

I need to check if **u** paramter is having http or https://access.dev.google.com then perform some action.

Comment: You can use the function mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery

Comment: Could be find with: `myhref.replace('%3A%2F%2F', '://').match(/u=(.*)$/g, '$1');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be:

```
var hr = 'http://docs.google.com?k=account&cs=This%20Site&u=http%3A%2F%2Faccess.dev.google.com'; //window.location.href;

var res = hr.match(/u=(http|https)%3A%2F%2Faccess.dev.google.com/g);
if(res != null) alert('ok');
else alert('not found');
```

Take a look to jensgram comment. /u= should be: [?&]u=

Comment: Consider prefixing the regex with `[?&]`, i.e., `/[?&]u=` in order to only match the `u` parameter, not `<whatever>u`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lovely non-regex version.

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
//assuming you want the path for http://docs.google.com?k=account&cs=This%20Site&u=https%3A%2F%2Faccess.dev.google.com


if(path.substring(path.indexOf('u='​)+2, path.indexOf('u=')+7) == 'https') {
    //execute if https, or change to +2, +6 for http
}​​​​​​​​​
```

I don't know if that's what you're looking for exactly, but it was worth a shot.