# Chrome Extension: Get Parameter from URL

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, url-parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

I am working on a extension for Chrome.
I already figured out how to get the URL from the actual Chrome-Tab.

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  document.getElementById('currentLink').innerHTML = tab.url;
});
```

But now i need to know how to get a specific Parameter from the URL.
I already tried out different Javascript-Functions but when i implement them, my Extension stops working.

So:
How can i get a specific parameter from the actual URL?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs As for the question: IDK, wasn't me. As for the answer: It's incorrect, and the updated answer is still incorrect (check the syntax..). I hope that you didn't "pity-upvote" the answer: Pity-upvotes are harmful: Votes indicate quality and correctness of an answer. A downvote is an encouragement to improve the post, not to personally attack the author.

Answer (score 4):

To get a query string in a single regexp, use:

```
var queryString = /^[^#?]*(\?[^#]+|)/.exec(tab.url)[1];
// Explanation of RegEx:
// ^[^#?]*                          (\?[^#]+   | )
// <Starts with any non-#/? string><query string OR nothing>
```

Then, use the following function to get the value of a specific key:

```
function getParameterByName(queryString, name) {
    // Escape special RegExp characters
    name = name.replace(/[[^$.|?*+(){}\\]/g, '\\$&');
    // Create Regular expression
    var regex = new RegExp("(?:[?&]|^)" + name + "=([^&#]*)");
    // Attempt to get a match
    var results = regex.exec(queryString);
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " ")) || '';
}

// Usage:
// Example: tab.url = "http://example.com/path?foo=bar&key_name=qs_value#"
var queryString = /\?[^#]+(?=#|$)|$/.exec(tab.url)[0];
var value = getParameterByName(queryString, 'qs_name');
// Result : value = "value";

// Example 2: Using the function to get a parameter from the current page's URL.
//  (e.g inside content script)
var value = getParameterByName(location.search, 'qs_name');
// Result : value = "value"
```

Comment: `;` is also a valid delimiter for params. Very rare, but easy enough to implement. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a regex, but this should work:

```
var queryString=url.match(/\?.+$)[0].split('#')[0]
```

This should work in most cases. I'll try to dig up the regex I had written for this some time ago.

Comment: "Get a *specific parameter*". And your regexp doesn't work at all: `/(\?[^=&;#]+=[^=&;#]+([;&][^=&;#]+=[^=&;#])*)?((#[^#]+)?)/.exec('http://foo.bar/e?e=4')` returns `[,,,,]`.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed this. I'm trying to build one that works.

Comment: hey guys, i found the solution!!

http://pastie.org/4376762

Comment: @user1361869 Please incorporate the solution in the answer, preferrably with an explanation why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Created simple function to get URL parameter in Javascript from a URL like this

**.....58e/web/viewer.html?page=*17*&getinfo=*33***

```
    function buildLinkb(param) {
        var val = document.URL;
        var url = val.substr(val.indexOf(param))  
        var n=parseInt(url.replace(param+"=",""));
        alert(n+1); 
    }
    buildLinkb("page");
```

OUTPUT : **18**