# How to make my JQuery code recognise a parameter in the URL and then choose a line of code

Tags: jquery, url, parameters

In the code below, I want to change the line of code that reads as:

```
$("#commentload"+ID).prepend(html);
```

So that if the parameter `order=1` is found in the URL, for example, `http://my.com?order=1`then it should execute.

```
$("#commentload"+ID).append(html);
```

Instead of

```
$("#commentload"+ID).prepend(html);
```

Hope you understand what I mean.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Update Status
   $(".update_button").click(function(){
      var updateval = $("#update").val();
      var dataString = 'update='+ updateval;
      if(updateval==''){
         alert("Please Enter Some Text");
      } else {
         $("#flash").show();
         $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('Loading Update...');
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "message_ajax.php?CID=" + CID + "&Id="+Id,
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
               $("#flash").fadeOut('slow');
               $("#commentload"+ID).prepend(html);
               $("#update").val('');
               $("#update").focus();
               $("#stexpand").oembed(updateval);
            }
         });
      }
      return false;
   });
   //commment Submit
});
```

Comment: I've formatted your post for you.  Please remember to indent code four spaces to format it.  The styling will usually recognize which language it is.  If it doesn't, you can prefix it with `<!-- language: lang-etc -->`, with `etc` being short-hand such as `js` for `javascript`, `css` for `cascading style sheets`, or similar.

Comment: Thanks Daedalus! I'm still new to the styling. You spoonfed me then, but I will learn from this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the current URL using `location.href` (or `location.search`, since you're only interested in the query portion). Search it for your parameter, for instance using a regex:

```
if ( /order=1/.test(location.href) )
    $("#commentload"+ID).append(html);
else
    $("#commentload"+ID).prepend(html);
```

If you need a more general solution, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1403888/520779) (or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values/901144#901144), as suggested by @naveen).

Comment: Many thanks!!!! I've been slaving away for more than an hour. This is most helpful.

Comment: +1: another more comprehensive link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values/901144#901144