# Conditionally open popup video based on URL query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, parameters

I have a page (somepage.aspx) that has a popup video on it. The video opens when a link is clicked using the js `$('.showVideo').live('click', function() {`

I have another page (otherpage.aspx) and would like to link to `/somepage.aspx` with some kind of URL parameter that automatically opens the video popup. Something like /`somepage.aspx?video=1 ...` based on the url parameter the video would open. How would I add this to my existing js?

Thanks

Comment: You are asking how to read a querystring/url value with JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's correct. Sorry if I worded that wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using this function you are able to detect the presence of `?video=1` in the url:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

Source: [Get escaped URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery)
Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/726427/pauloppenheim

Then you could do something like:

```
if(getURLParameter('video')==1){
  $(".showVideo").trigger('click');
}
```

edit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){               


    function getURLParameter(name) {
        return decodeURI(
            (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
        );
    }
    if(getURLParameter('video')==1){
      $(".showVideo").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Wrap the parameter name(video) in quotes `getURLParameter('video')`.

Another Edit

Wrap your click event handler in a function, basically remove everything form:

```
$('.showVideo').live('click', function() {
    //build overlay
    (...)
    return false;
});
```

Cut&paste it inside a function. Then just call the function from inside:

```
$('.showVideo').live('click', function() {
    my_function();
});
```

Then change the previous code to:

```
if(getURLParameter('video')==1){
     my_function()
}
```

Comment: Page from: http://bit.ly/RElMs2 (the link under 2008). I added the script to the head of http://bit.ly/RElNMt
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}  
if(getURLParameter(video)==1){
  $(".showVideo").trigger('click');
} 
 </script>

No luck, did I add that correctly?

Comment: @KevinW.me Your jQuery needs to be inside the $(document).ready function. I just looked at your source code at http://lg.priworks.com/overview.aspx?video=1. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Tried it their before too. I added to the video js in $(document).ready function. and still nothing.

Comment: Thanks "js/jquery/jquery.videobox.js" by the way

Comment: Clicking the video popup links on the page also no longer works

Comment: @KevinW.me that's because video was being treated as a variable and it was not assigned(if you are using chrome check your console). Don't forget to wrap it in quotes.

Comment: Any idea why after closing the video popup it would show CLOSE CLOSE text on the right of the sreen? http://bit.ly/REsb6y