# jquery script to detect parameter in url and call a link with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7

I have following scenario: User clicks on a link with parameter like this

```
www.abc.com/page1?xxx.
```

On **page1** I would like to have script that detects parameter xxx and runs a link with a class asap (no need to wait for dom to finish, it can be in background)(running a link opens modal window with some text). I use jquery 1.8.

Edit: I am using following code: based on this question [Conditionally open popup video based on URL query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746416/conditionally-open-popup-video-based-on-url-query-string)

```
(function($){ 

Drupal.behaviors.zzz = {
  attach: function (context) {

$(document).ready(function(){               


    function getURLParameter(name) {
        return decodeURI(
            (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
        );
    }
    if(getURLParameter('param')==1){
      $(".colorbox-node").trigger('click');
    }
});


}
};
})(jQuery);
```

However, there seems to be some loop jquery that prevents the page to finish loading. I suppose that is caused by colorbox plugin trying to set top value and looking at the console I can see "setting top" message constantly working until browser crashes. How to avoid this? Thank you

Comment: Yes it is. If you have a *specific* question, feel free to ask. In general, yes/no questions are not a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a start to your question.

You can get the parameter from document.location.search.  If you have multiple parameters, you might need to apply a regular expression to it.

```
 var loc = document.location.search;
```

You can then open your new window

```
 window.open(loc);
```

JQuery UI would be helpful in constructing a modal popup.