# Modify iframe.src without entry to history object

Tags: iframe, history, back, vimeo

I have an iframe in my web page.  I modify the src property via javascript like so:

```
document.getElementById('myiframe').src = 'http://vimeo.com/videoid1';
document.getElementById('myiframe').src = 'http://vimeo.com/videoid2';
document.getElementById('myiframe').src = 'http://vimeo.com/videoid3';
```

However, everytime I do this, it's logged into the browser's history.  So everytime I press back in the browser window, the iframe content goes from videoid3 to videoid2 to videoid1.  If I press back again, the entire page goes back.

I would like to modify the iframe src with javascript WITHOUT logging an entry into the browser's history.  So if i click the browser back button, the entire page goes back without updating the iframe.

I tried doing something like:

```
document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.location.replace('http://vimeo.com/videoid1');
document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.location.replace('http://vimeo.com/videoid2');
document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.location.replace('http://vimeo.com/videoid3');
```

Although this made the browser back button behave the way I wanted to, it broke certain things in the vimeo video.  Vimeo REQUIRES you to change urls via the iframe.src instead of contentWindow.location.replace().

As such, how do I modify the iframe.src WITHOUT logging into history?

**Related**
This is actually one of the solutions I'm exploring to solve the main problem, which I posted here  [History object back button with iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722089/history-object-back-button-with-iframes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821359/reload-an-iframe-without-adding-to-the-history  I think this answer will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/8681618/2009041

Answer (score 20, accepted):

don't change the src, just replace the old iframe with a new one?

```js
const urls = [
  "http://bing.com",
  "http://google.com",
  "http://duckduckgo.com"
];

function next() {
  if(urls.length==0) return;
  const original = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
  const newFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
  newFrame.src = urls.pop();
  original.parentNode.replaceChild(newFrame, original);
}

nextbtn.addEventListener("click", () => next());
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 300px;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<p>let's test some iframes</p>
<button id="nextbtn">next</button>
  <iframe />
```

No history states. Same functionality. Everyone wins.

Comment: if you want, you can post this answer to my other question that i mentioned.  THen i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var iframe = $('#iframe')[0];  
iframe.contentWindow.location.replace(newUrl);
```

Comment: The question explicitly says that this solution is not okay due to Vimeo requirements.