# Creating a new DOM node instead of re-rendering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

I'm using an iframe component that loads a cross-origin url passed down via `props`. Navigating the iframe to a new url via props pushes a new entry into the iframe's history, which hijacks the browser's 'back' button. This is expected behavior for cross-origin iframes whenever their src url changes.

Is it possible, then, **to simply create a new iframe instead of changing the src**? My assumption is that this would destroy whatever internal state the iframe had, thus preventing new entries into the 'back' button's history.

The iframe component (adapted from [react-iframe](https://github.com/svenanders/react-iframe)):

```
// ETA: using React.Component instead of 
// PureComponent yields the same back button behavior
const Iframe = class extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        return React.createElement('iframe', {
            ref: 'iframe',
            frameBorder: '0',
            src: this.props.url,
            sandbox: this.props.sandbox,
            referrerpolicy: 'no-referrer',
            target: '_parent',
            allowFullScreen: this.props.allowFullScreen || false,
            style: Object.assign(
                {},
                {
                    position: this.props.position || 'absolute',
                    display: this.props.display || 'block',
                    height: this.props.height || '100%',
                    width: this.props.width || '100%'
                },
                this.props.styles || {}
            ),
            height: this.props.height || '100%',
            width: this.props.width || '100%'
        });
    }
};
```

ETA: I am assuming that creating a new underlying iframe will prevent entries into history [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737365/modify-iframe-src-without-entry-to-history-object), which reads:

> don't change the src, just replace the old iframe with a new one?
>   No history states. Same functionality. Everyone wins.

```
 <!doctype html>

 <style> iframe {
     width: 300px;
     height:300px; } </style>

 <script> var urls = ["http://bing.com", "http://google.com",
 "http://duckduckgo.com"];

 function next() {
     if(urls.length==0) return;
    var original = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
     var newFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
     newFrame.src = urls.pop();
     var parent = original.parentNode;
     parent.replaceChild(newFrame, original); } </script>

 <p>let's test some iframes</p> <button onclick="next()">next</button>
 <iframe />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `Component` and not the `PureComponent` in such case, or instead - use the `forceupdate` method.

The `PureComponent` implements `shouldComponentUpdate()` with a shallow prop and state comparison, which caused your component to not re-render.

Comment: thanks @Dekel. I changed it to a `Component`, but the back button is still navigating the iframe's history, not the parent page. Am I wrong to assume that creating a new underlying iframe will prevent the iframe's history from accumulating entries?

Comment: I think it's not related to react at all - it's the way browsers work with iframes. Did you check it not with a react app? :)

Comment: i haven't checked it directly, but I am basing my assumption off of the answer in this post (which I'll add to OP): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737365/modify-iframe-src-without-entry-to-history-object

Comment: I'm afraid the answer will be "no" :( https://jsfiddle.net/h2rt2pwu/ here is an example, but because there are multiple layers of iframes there - here are the instructions on how to check it. 1. Click the next (you will get the duckduckgo). 2. Search for something. 3. Click on "next" (you will get bind). 4. Click with your mouse inside the "result" iframe (outside the bind iframe). Click "back" in the browser - you will get duckduckgo back inside the iframe.