# Parameters for a JS - which is the best way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, performance

I want to load a JS and his behaviour should differ depending of one parameter. I thought one of the ways to do this could be:

```
<script src="script.js?type=a" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script.js?type=b" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
```

Then, I would obtain the parameter using regex, like:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null;
}
```

(above function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery)).

However, I'm not sure if this is the best approach for this. Do you suggest any other way to do this, like, loading global variables inside the `<script></script>` and then read them from the JS?

Comment: behave differently how? Is it possible for the parameter to change the output of the js file? Also does it make sense that the parameter could change multiple times?

Comment: I don't see anything in your question related to regex other than tangentially in your source code.

Comment: I think that is enough to put the tag in my question? If it is not, feel free to remove it (you or any moderator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be a better way to organize your code in general, but an easier way to configure a parameter than a URL query would be to simply call the defined functions with an argument:

External script (foo.js):

```
function foo(param) {
    console.log(param);
}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="foo.js"></script>
<script>foo("parameter value");</script>
```

Edit: Here's an example of "configuring" a parameter without immediately calling anything (basically, a simple closure):

```
function (param) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Use param
    });
}
```

`$(document).ready` is already an async call so this is simpler than it might be otherwise, but in general you can use an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression): `(function (param) { })(paramValue)`

Comment: I forgot to say (sorry) that my script is $(document).ready based, so it's not the solution I was looking for but I know what you mean, thank you though.

Comment: You can still do it fairly easily. I'll amend my answer with an example.

Comment: I think this is the smartest way to do what you're asking without knowing much more about your specific rules. Url param would be a hacky way to achieve what this solution is doing. Plus you have the added bonus of being explicit in your intent.

Comment: I think I'm following this approach to do what I want to do. It seems clean and won't cause any issue in the future at first glance imho. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `getURLParameter` function you have given will use the URL that you see in the address bar, not the one the `<script>` was loaded with.

To get that, you will need to replace `location.search` with

```
Array.prototype.pop.call(document.getElementsByTagName('script')).getAttribute("src");
```

Comment: You're right - I didn't pay too much attention to the example, it was just to illustrate what I meant, but I'm not using it actually. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would just set a global variable before getting the external script, then use it inside:

```
<script>var someParameter = 'a';</script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: This looks like a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I would not do this. Magic global variables are a headache.

Comment: I thought about this as I mentioned, but I think it's not the most elegant solution and, as said above, kind of a nightmare to maintain?

Comment: Fair enough - I suppose it depends on how complex your parameters are going to be and how often you will use them.  I only made this suggestion as I had done a little research into parameters before and found this to be the best way in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your javascript in php and use

```
var parameters = <?php echo json_encode($_GET); ?>
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return parameters[name];
}
```

Comment: It has to be pure javascript. I used that workaround in the past but I'd prefer to get rid of it in this case (otherwise I would have to run PHP support for my script in my server).