# using a href redirect and call JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, href

I have a simple index page in which the door open and the user see the menu. Now when user reaches the contact us page and he moves to index page again.. he found the door closed.. I dont want that..I want when user once open the door ,again reaching the index file he see the menu..
For this `<a href="index.htmlPLUSE CODE TO OPEN DOOR USING JS"/>`
This is line is very self explanatory..I want when user navigates to home page the function for JS calls automtically.
I can't really use the document.ready() or onload calls as I used them already.. May be I need to use some conditional statement.
Anyone who can help

Comment: There are many ways to do that, but pretty much all of them will require something to be done when the page loads (document.ready). A simple URL parameter won't suffice, most likely. Why are you ruling out document.ready?

Comment: Use a cookie to record the open/closed state of the menu.  Then, on `ready()`, check the cookie value to see if the menu should be opened.

Comment: Or maybe `href="index.html#open-sesame"`...

Comment: Create a cookie/session; use its timeout to calculate all returning visits to index pages.

Comment: @bfavaretto because I am already doing stuff in document.ready. suppose if I call dooropen() function in document.ready then when the site first loads it autoatically opens the door.. :(

Comment: @NRohler thanks for the idea.. but I want to use simple approach.If I have to use cookie then I can do it simply in PHP.. with url parameter

Comment: You have to call it conditionally, based on cookie value or URL parameter (or hash). You can't call js from an URL.

Comment: how about using IF condition in document.ready, IF(document.URL holds #container then call door open function..

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. You can use `window.location.hash` to get just the hash parameter (like `#something`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass parameters to the url (`/index.html?open=true`), and read them using JavaScript:

```
function isOpen() {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(open + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

(from [Get escaped URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery))