# Link and open accordian from another page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am hoping you can help me. I have an accordian system working on the home page of a site I am working on. This works with jQuery:

```
$('.accordionButton').click(function() {
    //REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
    $('.accordionButton').removeClass('on');
    //NO MATTER WHAT WE CLOSE ALL OPEN SLIDES
    $('.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');
    //IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
        //ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
        $(this).addClass('on');
        //OPEN THE SLIDE
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
     }   
 });

//ADDS THE .OVER CLASS FROM THE STYLESHEET ON MOUSEOVER 
$('.accordionButton').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('over');

//ON MOUSEOUT REMOVE THE OVER CLASS
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('over');                                        
});

$('.accordionContent').hide();
```

HTML

```
<div class="accordionButton">Products</div>
<div class="accordionContent products">
        <p>Content here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want a link on another page that when clicked goes to the home page and opens this specific accordion. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have a parameter linking to your content and then [parse it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery) onload.