# extract value from href tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Url is generated like this

```
/Home/LoadData?page=2&activeTab=House
```

How can I grab activeTab value?

Comment: use `.split();` its not jQuery function but its core javascript function

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name+ '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

and call it as `getURLParameter('activeTab');`

[From Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

please add this function in your javascript

and you can pass param name and you can get value

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
    if(results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

hope it's help for you .

Answer (score 1):

You can use split

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/65EXN/)**

```
url.split('activeTab=')[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript's `substr()` and `.lastIndexOf()`:

```
var url = '/Home/LoadData?page=2&activeTab=House'; // window.location.href;

var activeTab = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('=')+1); // outputs House
```

#### [Find in FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gjkrZ/)

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/Home/LoadData?page=2&activeTab=House';
    alert(decodeURI(
            (RegExp('activeTab=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(url)||[,null])[1]
        ));
});
```