# Show hidden div for short period of time depending on PHP $GET in url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have two different hidden divs. They are hidden with css "display:none;". Both of the divs contains a single image. Upon page load I would like div 1 to be shown for a short period of time if the url is "www.myserver.com/index.php?succeded=yes" and div 2 to be shown instead if the url says "www.myserver.com/index.php?succeded=no".

Can this be done with jquery?

Comment: Of course, you just need to look at the queryString to see if it's yes/no, and show/hide the divs accordingly

Comment: Of course it is, just look at [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read "succeded": [Get escaped URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery).

Using the function `function getURLParameter(name)`:

```
if (getURLParameter('succeded') == 'yes') {
    $('#mydiv').show();
    window.setTimeout(function () { $('#mydiv').hide(); }, 5000); // hide after 5s
}
```

that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.split()` method of jQuery:

```
var url = "www.myserver.com/index.php?succeded=yes"; // window.location.href;
var str = url.split('?')[1];

if(str == "succeded=yes"){
    $('.yesdiv').show().delay(2000).hide();
}else{
    $('.nodiv').show().delay(2000).hide();
}
```

Comment: Also consider the following [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values).

Comment: Yup thats great but OP asked "`Can this be done with jquery?`". so this is the way to get it with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, parameters in the URL are *GET* parameters, not POST.

And of course this can be done – either you already check for this parameter server-side and then just output the appropriate JS code; or you check the URL of the current document in JS yourself, using `location.search` to access the query string part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

i think it would be easier if you parse the php variable to js

```
var any = "<?=isset($_GET['success'])?$_GET['success']:''?>";
```