# selecting language from drop down menu with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/hr5aH/

I am jQuery beginner, I have just small problem here..
when I select language from the drop down menu the page refresh, but the drop down menu dose not show me which language I picked up..it's remain Choose Language - however the URL shows me which language I picked up, which is what I want, but not the drop down menu

**for example if I choose from the drop down menu English**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

        $("form").change(function(){

            $("select[name='lang']").attr('selected','selected');
            $("form").submit();

        })

})
</script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="<?php htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="get">

    <select name="lang">

        <option value="">Choose Language</option>
        <option value="English">English</option>
        <option value="Arabic">Arabic</option>
        <option value="French">French</option>

    </select>
```

I see the URL `http://127.0.0.1/index.php?lang=english` 
**(Which what I want)**

but the drop down menu remain on choose language - I just want to the drop down menu shows me the language as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remeber the last language seleted then you need to use a cookie. Use the jquery cookie plugin.

```
//checks if the cookie has been set

if($.cookie('remember_select') != null) {

    // set the option to selected that corresponds to what the cookie is set to

    $('.select_class option[value="' + $.cookie('remember_select') + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');

}

// when a new option is selected this is triggered

$('.select_class').change(function() {

    // new cookie is set when the option is changed

    $.cookie('remember_select', $('.select_class option:selected').val(), { expires: 90, path: '/'});

});
```

Here is what your `select` would look like:

```
<select class="select_class">
    <option value="1">Row 1</option>
    <option value="2">Row 2</option>
    <option value="3">Row 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I +1'd, but it looks like he's looking for an after form submit. So I think the best bet is to check for the existence of `location.query` and if so, check for the length of `lang`, and then apply the value.

Comment: thanks vector, i did't cover the jquery cookie plugin - iam just beginner, but any way i will give it a try... so i don't have to wrap the drop down menu with <form></form>, just plain select box with a class and the jquery will take care of the rest..? correct

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$("select[name='lang']").change(function(){
    $("form").submit();
})
```

and to this you can add:

```
<option selected disable value="">Choose Language</option>
```

to prevent errors in you PHP

## **EDIT:**

`$_SESSION['language'] = $_GET['lang']` and in your jQuery

```
var selected_lang = '<?php echo $_SESSION["language"]; ?>';
$("select[name='lang']").val(selected_lang);
```

Comment: thanks Memolition for replying : i have tried this as well, but it seems to be the same result. the drop down menu remains on choose language...

Comment: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error]  

var selected_lang = "<br />

Comment: make an `echo $_SESSION['language']` to see what is the value of the `php` language variable and an `console.log(selected_lang);` to see check the `jQuery` variable value

Comment: cause it seems like php is not setting right the `$_SESSION['language']` variable value so try to `echo` the `$_GET['lang']` variable where you are setting the `$_SESSION['language']` variable in your php

Comment: <select name="lang" onchange="this.form.submit()">
i just added onchange to check weather $_SESSION['language']  getting the value from the url and it's working i have echo the  $_SESSION['language'] and it showing me a value

Comment: the console.log return always french, even if i pick another language

Comment: try to unset the variable `unset($_SESSION['language'])` before setting it to the `<select>` value

Answer (score 0):

This needs a bit of php magic coupled with your HTML code:

**PHP Code**

```
</head>
    <body>

    <form action="<?php htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="get">

    <select name="lang">

        <option value="">Choose Language</option>
        <?php foreach(array('English','Arabic','French') as $lang) ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $lang; ?>" <?php if ($_GET['lang']==$lang) echo "selected"; ?>><? echo $lang; ?></option>
       ?>
    </select>
```

**Explanation:** The php code checks for your url and selects the appropriate option from the select list.

**Tip:** If you wish to have a cleaner code, place all your language values in an array and loop through it to generate your dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Your js script must be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("form").change(function(){

            $("select[name='lang']").attr('selected','selected');
            $("form").submit();

        })
        var lang=getURLParameter('lang');
        if(lang!='null')
             $("select[name='lang']").prop('value',lang);

})
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

Link for details of `getURLParameter()` function: [Get URL parameter with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery)