# PHP parse address bar in order to forward to specific content

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

My webpage ([www.gagandipsingh.com](http://www.gagandipsingh.com)) is coded mostly on one page, with links calling the following script, which show/hide certain div sections...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function show() {
        document.getElementById(arguments[0]).style.display='block';
        for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            // alert(arguments[i]);
             document.getElementById(arguments[i]).style.display='none';
        }
        return false;
    } 
</script>
```

My question is, is it possible to parse the address bar so that a certain div may be shown/hidden? I found i could get variables (ex: gagandipsingh.com?p=code) so I attempted my requirment with the following...

```
<?php 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="show_hide.js"></script>';
    if (isset($_GET['p'])) 
    { 
        $page = $_GET['p'];
        if ($page == 'code'){
            echo "show('Code','Media','Home', 'Resume','Contact')";
        }
    } 
    else 
    { 
        echo "Variable not set."; 
    } 
?>
```

which did not work; the function never gets called, just prints that message. You can see an example of that at http://gagandipsingh.com/test/?p=code

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to put the code inside `<script>` block.

Comment: show_hide.js is simply the code included in the first block, the function show()

Comment: You can get the parameters with Javascript also. Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the function call to be executed instead of just being displayed as part of the web page, you have to enclose it in a `<script>` tag.

```
<?php 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="show_hide.js"></script>';
    if (isset($_GET['p'])) 
    { 
        $page = $_GET['p'];
        if ($page == 'code'){
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>show('Code','Media','Home', 'Resume','Contact');</script>";
        }
    } 
    else 
    { 
        echo "Variable not set."; 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: This was it, perfect! will click the green checkmark as soon as it lets me. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check this file
http://gagandipsingh.com/test/show_hide.js

1.Why this contain `<script type = "text/javascript">` and this `</script>` in JS file.

Maybe your code like this

```
<?php 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="show_hide.js"></script>';
    if (isset($_GET['p'])) 
    { 
        $page = $_GET['p'];
        if ($page == 'code'){
            echo'<script type="text/javascript">';
            echo "show('Code','Media','Home', 'Resume','Contact')";
            echo'</script>';
        }
    } 
    else 
    { 
        echo "Variable not set."; 
    } 
?>
```