# Is it possible to get URL parameters in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx-2, ria, url-parameters

I'm building a JavaFX application which will run in browser.
Is it possible to get the app URL, like localhost/Java/MyApp/dist/index.html?x=123, in JavaFX?

I need to receive that "x" parameter.

Comment: Your question should be formulated like "how to get applet page parameters for JavaFX-2 applet"

Comment: Try to use Application.getParameters() - will it work?

Comment: Also, some access to the page you can get, having called Application.getHostServices().getWebContext().eval(<Javascript code>).

Comment: @AlexanderKirov getParameters() lead me to getParameters().getNamed().get("baseURL"); which get me the complete URL (localhost/Java/MyApp/dist/index.html?x=123) so as getHostServices().getDocumentBase().

In both ways i'll have to handle the string, but at least i know it's possible. I'll give a try in "jewelsea" suggestion as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get url parameters from the page: [Get escaped URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery)

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null;
}
```

Once you have the parameters you can pass the parameters to the embedded JavaFX application using the JavaFX deployment toolkits DTJava.js functions.  See section [7.3.3 Pass Parameters to a Web Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deployment_toolkit.htm#FBJHAIHG) of the JavaFX deployment guide.

```
<!-- Example 7-7 Pass Parameters to an Embedded Application -->

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://java.com/js/dtjava.js"></script>
    <script>
        function deployIt() {
            // deployment guide sample modified by me to show 
            // getting the zipcode parameter from the url instead of hardcoding it.
            //var zipcode = 95054; 
            var zipcode = getURLParameter("zipcode");

            dtjava.embed(
                {            id: "myApp",
                            url: "Map.jnlp",
                          width: 300,
                         height: 200,
                    placeholder: "place",
                    params: {
                              mode: "streetview",
                              zip: zipcode
                    }
                },
                { javafx: "2.1+" },
                {}
            );
        }
        dtjava.addOnloadCallback(deployIt);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="place"></div>
</body>
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deployment_toolkit.htm#BABJHEJA

As the JavaFX deployment guide says, to access parameters in the application code, use the [getParameters()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters%28%29) method of the Application class. For example:

```
String zipcode = app.getParameters().getNamed("zip");
```

Comment: Seems, jQuery can be called from Object obj  = Application.getHostServices().getWebContext().eval(<Javascript code>), which will be much shorter (but I don't know, if it will work).

Comment: The solution you suggested is more likely the solution i used when i faced the same problem in a Flex + Java project. I'll give it a try and get back with an answer.

Comment: In my first try i edited the html generated by NetBeans, adding your suggestions. When i run the application the file was deleted and recreated. So I created another index.html file in another folder (/src). Right click on the project (in NetBeans interface), Properties, Run (Check if it's running in browser) and changed option WebPage to my index.html path. It's working pretty good now. Thank you.