# Using a link to launch a page with an onclick?

Tags: html, onclick

I'm not much of a programming person so forgive me if I don't explain this well.

I have a web site with a home page. There are a couple of menus across the top, each with a submenu. When you select one of the submenus, that "page" comes up in the center of the page. So, for example, if I select the menu item biography, the "page_BIO" will load into the main part of the screen. The script looks like this:

Band Bio

It works perfectly . . . all's good in the world when you're on the page.

HOWEVER . .

If I want to have a link to my "biography" from another site or page, it will open http://www.mydomain.com/index#!/page_BIO BUT it won't launch the actual "onclick" script. It basically just loads the index.html page and, from there, you can select what you want.

I'm trying to find a way to launch the index.html page but WITH the BIO page loaded. So, if this makes sense, I want to launch the onclick that resides on one page withe a link from another page.

Does this make sense? Is this possible?

stu

Comment: Can you post some of your code please?

Answer (score 1):

On the index.html, you can read the parameters being passed using the code here: [Get escaped URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery)

If a certain parameter is detected, you can then invoke your JavaScript to load the bio page.

From the referring page, you can then pass the required parameter.

Hope this helps!