# jquerymobile url parameters

Tags: jquery-mobile, parameters, cordova

Have asked two questions and not getting an answer and having spent a few hours trying to find the answer without success I am wondering if someone can finally help me.

I need to generate dynamic urls and pass through parameters on jquerymobile.

example..

```
<a href="menu.php?id=2">Menu 2</a>
<a href="results.php?id=4">Result No. 4</a>
```

The above urls need to be dynamic and I need to be able to pass through a parameter of ID.

I then need to get the id parameter on the given page.

I have read lots regarding changePage etc but I can specify in the function which page will be next as it needs to be dynamic. I also need the ajax transitions to work so ajax-false needs to be true.

Please help once and for all and provide me with sample code.

Kind Regards.

Comment: So you want to navigate from page A (with some links similar to what you've posted) to page B and in page B, you want to be able to pick up the ID which was in the URL?

Comment: Not sure if you're still looking for a solution to this but I created a [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) for this

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to get the url parameter on the page you navigated in, use something similar to the following.

It uses pageshow event to get the ID from the current URL.

I have used the function from the answer on this question - [Get escaped URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery):

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function(event, data) {
    var id = getURLParameter("id"); 
    console.log("ID = " + id);
});

function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

Comment: Brill I will try it out, clearly I have been over thinking it!

Answer (score 0):

If the above regex doesn't work means try with this change

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
return decodeURI(
    (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(window.location.href)||[,null])[1]
);
```

}