# How do I make a link that pre-fills a form checkbox?

Tags: forms, linked-list

I have a page called contact.htm with a working form.  One of the checkbox fields on the form is named Garden (so either it is checked or not when using the form).

I have another page that I want to link to my form page, so that if a user clicks a particular link, they are sent to the form page and the field Garden is pre-clicked.

I have not been able to do this though I have tried several methods...such as:

a `href="contact.htm?checkbox=Garden,on"` or 
a `href="contact.htm?checkbox=Garden,checked"` or 
a `href="contact.htm?input type="checkbox" name="Garden" value="checked"`, and some others.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use JavaScript on the target webpage to process the argument and fill the values in. There is no automatic way of doing this just by URL.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8764051/389837) shows how to retrieve URL arguments from JavaScript. From there, it's a matter of using standard JavaScript or JQuery to fill the values in.

Comment: Can you mark my answer as correct? There is no way to do what you're asking without writing some JavaScript, but someone else might find this useful.