# Using name of hyperlink

Tags: html, mysql, c, hyperlink, cgi

My program includes creating hyperlinks for each row in a MySQL table. So I used the C MYSQL API to retrieve the contents of the table:

```
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
  {
....//some code to print the data....
  }
```

I can output the data. But we need to create hyperlinks in each of the printed results and it should link to another page where I can use that certain string for other processing:

```
<a href="processfile">text1</a>
<a href="processfile">text2</a>
```

The problem is: I need to display the string the user clicked in another page. But how would I know what string the user clicked since they are pointing to the same file?

Comment: I think people make the links something like: `<a href="processfile?param=text1">text1</a>`

Comment: In an onclick you could even easily get the innerHTML of the anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include extra information within the links that would allow you to look it up within your table.

For example:

```
<a href="processfile?param=text1">text1</a>
<a href="processfile?param=text2">text2</a>
```

If the text isn't guaranteed to be unique, perhaps include the row ID there instead.

You can read these extra parameters via

[Get escaped URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-javascript-or-jquery)

if you want to process it clientside or via reading the GET parameters in some other way depending on what you are using server-side.

Comment: How would I then retrieve the name `text1` in another c cgi script?

Comment: That's really a different question. Either search Stackoverflow for how to read GET parameters with C CGI or create a new question for this.

Comment: is the name `param` in `param=text1` arbitrarily chosen?

Comment: Yes. You could have multiple parameters if you wanted to (i.e. ?foo=1&bar=2) and then on the other side you can read in the values for foo and bar.  (But use a library for that rather than trying to parse the string yourself.)

Comment: I want to but we're not allowed to use a library. But I can parse it using `strtok`.

Comment: If you don't use a library, there are special cases you have to deal with (such as escaping characters).  Since you cannot use a library (sounds like a class project), just make sure you test it well for the inputs you expect.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I already know to deal with simple key-value pairs like that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36293/discussion-between-jared-sohn-and-jkta)

Answer (score 0):

You can use get function there

like..,

```
<a href="processfile/?str=text1">text1</a>
<a href="processfile/?str=text2">text2</a>
```

and you can get the string in your another page using,

```
<?php

    $string = $_GET['str']
    //do your process

?>
```

Comment: I don't know how to use PHP. I am using C.

Comment: can you clear You need this string to be displayed in your new page or you have to make process with that string....?

Comment: I both need to display the string and process the string.

Comment: can you say what API you are using to integrate with APACHE and upload your processfile backend coding where you need to process.

Comment: I am using MYSQL C API.

Comment: @JKTA, Anto is asking about the CGI library (cgic, libcgi, ... ), MYSQL does not speak with HTTP server

Comment: I think I don't use any of those libraries since we are not allowed.

Comment: Can you say how you output your data taken By MySQL API..?