# How get variable GET with jquery and HTML

Tags: jquery, variables, get

Am trying getting the value of variable GET... this is my code:

```
$('.x').append("<li><a class='smsContact' href='#SMS2?telefone=testeValue></a>");
```

Comment: You are trying to get a value from the querystring with javascript? This looks like it could help you [Get URL parameter with JavaScript or jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: sorry guys ... I edited ... the correct code its now above

Comment: try this http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "variable GET"?  If you are referring to the `a` element's `href` attribute, and specifically the parts that would be available on a PHP GET command at the other end...

Using jQuery it would look like this:

[Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xwhLT/1/)

```
$('.smsContact').click(function() {
    xx = $(this).attr('href'); 
    alert('href is:  ' + xx);
    justval = xx.split('=');
    yy = justval[1];
    alert('Just the value is:  ' + yy);
});
```

Comment: Terrible variable names there. Can't you be bothered to teach starters how to properly write clean and self-documenting code? You're also polluting the global variable scope this way, by the way.

Comment: Very good point. This is totally throw-away code, intended only for example, so I won't update variable names here. However, in future I will think twice and thrice. Thank you for making this point. +1