# Pass javascript url parameter to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a bit of javascript (shown below in a simplified format) which is the "ad tag" from the ad server that brings up an ad unit on the html page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adserverdomain.net;pcode=1234;city=nameofcity;suburb=nameofsuburb"></script>
```

The javascript has more variable but I've just shown one.

Below this I have a `<div>` in which I'd like to pull the variable "pcode" from the above javascript and display it's value using

```
$('div').html("");
```

So the `<div>` needs to be populated with the value "1234".

Any idea how I can do this? Thanks

EDIT: I've updated the url (added .net and some other variables after pcode to avoid confusion). Also, I don't have access to the initial script, so I can't add an id to it. The script is generated by the ad server and it always has the variable pcode (with a different value). just need to be able to display that in another div on the same html page.

Comment: Parsing `src` attribute is not an option?

Comment: Is it `;pcode=1234` or `?pcode=1234`?

Comment: $('div').html("1234"); ?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-javascript-or-jquery ?

Comment: Check here https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/6386183

Comment: where do you get the pcode value?

Comment: pcode value is generated by the ad server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adserverdomain;pcode=1234;city=sajdhsk;suburb=asdsadas"></script>
<div id="pcode"></div>
<div id="city"></div>
<div id="suburb"></div>
```

then

```
var pcodesrc = $('script[src^="http://adserverdomain;"]').attr('src');

$('#pcode').html(pcodesrc.match(/pcode=(.+?)(?=(;|$))/)[1])
$('#city').html(pcodesrc.match(/city=(.+?)(?=(;|$))/)[1])
$('#suburb').html(pcodesrc.match(/suburb=(.+?)(?=(;|$))/)[1])
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RjrP7/)

or

```
$('#pcode').html(pcodesrc.match(/pcode=([^;]+)/)[1])
$('#city').html(pcodesrc.match(/city=([^;]+)/)[1])
$('#suburb').html(pcodesrc.match(/suburb=([^;]+)/)[1])
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PG2bz/)

Comment: thanks but i can't edit the initial <script>, so i can't add the id="pcode"

Comment: i'm getting very close with this...is ".match(/pcode=(\d+)/)[1]" meant to be different if the value of pcode is a not numbers but something like "city" (text)?

Comment: in your demo fiddle, if i put "pcode=abcd" (in the script) instead of "1234", it doesn't work. any ideas? thanks for your help

Comment: @pixeltocode that can be fixed easily using `pcodesrc.match(/pcode=(.+)/)[1]`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36662/discussion-between-pixeltocode-and-arun-p-johny)

Answer (score 0):

Try this with url.Actually the below code get data from url querystring.Edit it and give your url.

```
function getUrlVars() {
            var vars = [], hash;
            var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
                hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                vars.push(hash[0]);
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
            }
            return vars;
        }

var me = getUrlVars()["pcode"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this buddy

```
function getvalues()
    {
        var values = {};
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) { values[key] = value;});
        return values;
    }
```

whenever you want to use it

```
var value = getvalues()["pcode"];
```

Use this value to put in your html element