# keep javascript menu open on new page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a menu that slides in from outside of the page. The problem is that when you click on an item in the menu and load a new page, the new page loads with the menu closed. Is there a way to tell the browser to keep the menu open after a new page load?

this is the code that opens up the menu

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
         $("#closeIcon").hide()
         $(".left").width('0%');
         $(".right").width('100%');
      });

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#menuIcon").click(function(){
        $(".left").animate({width:'10%'}, "500");
        $(".right").animate({width:'90%'}, "500");
        $("#nav").animate({
                    left: '30%',
                  }, "500" );
        $("#menuIcon").fadeOut(500)
        $("#closeIcon").fadeIn(500)
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#closeIcon").click(function(){
        $(".left").animate({width:'0%'}, "500");
        $(".right").animate({width:'100%'}, "500");
        $("#nav").animate({
                    left: '0',
                }, "500" );
        $("#menuIcon").fadeIn(500)
        $("#closeIcon").fadeOut(500)
      });
    });
    </script>
```

this is the html:

```
<html>
<div id="menu" >
            <div id="menuIcon">             
                    <a href="javascript: void(0)">
                        <img src="images/menuIcon.png">
                    </a>
            </div>
            <div id="closeIcon">
                    <a href="javascript: void(0)"> 
                        <img src="images/closeIcon.png">
                    </a>
            </div>
        </div>
</html>


<div class="left">
   <div id="nav">                       
  <div id="accordion">          
      </div> <!--ends accordion-->
   </div>
</div>          

<div class="right">
<div id="content"> 
</div><!--ends content-->
</div><!--ends right-->
```

Comment: You have to use a form of persistent to retain info beyond navigation -- [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie), [DOM Storage](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/Storage.html), etc.

Comment: Do you use any server side language? Or plain HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can't keep jQuery event when you leave the page.
If you leave the page, add class on element to have your menu open.

You can pass parameters in the link of your  to know what action you must to make

Moreover, you can use only one `$(document).ready();`

Comment: This is why I say "can". It's just an help if he don't know.

Comment: Sorry for my english. Sometimes I haven't the good words. Thank's.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I am still very much a beginner with javascript and function mostly by trial and error. The javascript in the menu works fine at the moment, if I try to remove the other document.ready it stops working. How should I write it?

Comment: When I say remove other $(document).ready, I want to say move all .ready content in the same one. But even if you make that, it's no the problem here. You can't load page and keep your js event. You can pass a parameter on the link to know the state of your menu when you load the other page.

Comment: @DonovanCharpin Sorry my previous comments. Finally caught up to what you meant. I was just reading it wrong. :)

Comment: If you want keep your menu in the same state, you must have a dynamic website and refresh your content with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a `GET` parameter to your new page so you can know when you need to show the menu.

Check this page to know more about how to get URL parameters with jQuery : [Get escaped URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-javascript-or-jquery)

Also, I think you forgot to add some html to your example. What are those elements?
`.left` `.right` `#nav`

Comment: I've added the html to for the .left .right... essentially left and right resize and nav slides in when you click on menuIcon

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading a new page on the window, why not load the page using AJAX and replace the content of your page with the new content?

Something like:

```
<html>
<div id="menu" >
            <div id="menuIcon">             
                    <a href="javascript: void(0)">
                        <img src="images/menuIcon.png">
                    </a>
            </div>
            <div id="closeIcon">
                    <a href="javascript: void(0)"> 
                        <img src="images/closeIcon.png">
                    </a>
            </div>
</div>
<div id="body">
<!--Body here-->
</div>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$("a").click(function(e){e.preventDefault();loadNew(this.href);});
function loadNew(href){
    $.ajax({
      url: href,
      cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) {
        $( "#body" ).replaceWith( $(html).find("#body") );
      });
}
```

This will make the transition look smother also.

Comment: I just noticed you updated your HTML code. But I think you get my point with mine.

Comment: I've never used ajax before, I will have to read up on it, but before I delve into that, I must add that my website is using django cms and the pages are django template files. So can this technic still work in this case?

Comment: I'm not familiar with django, but it should. What ajax basically does is load a webpage in the background and then do something with the information it has. For instance, in my example, I'm loading whichever url I sent as the href parameter. Then after it's done loading, I extract the element with `id="body"` of that document (with `$(html).find("#body")`), and replace it in the current document's element with `id="body"`. Everything else (including the menu and javascript variables) are left untouched.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have one $(document).ready() function because it will only be called once.

Try breaking your code apart and have your $(document).ready() call these parts, then repost if you are still having trouble.

ie

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         closeIcon();
         menuIcon();
      });

function closeIcon(){
//dostuff
}

function menuIcon(){
//dostuff
}
```