# send variable value with link to html - ajax page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I get a value in my index.html page that I would like to send to another .html page when I load that page. I´m using jQuery - ajax to load the page.

```
<a href="pagetoload.html?myvariable='+myvarvaluetosend+'">Load page</a>
```

Something like that...
But how do I get it in the page I´m loading...I´m totally blank :-)

With .asp I know how to do it but not when the resiving page has to be a .html page?

Any input really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$("a").attr("href", "pagetoload.html?myvariable="+myvarvaluetosend);
```

See [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rYeyA/1/)

Comment: Thanks Benoit and how do I get it in the page that I load and put it in a variable there?

Comment: You mean, how to use `myvariable` insinde `pagetoload.html` ? Usually you want to handle this on server side...

Comment: If you do want to handle it on client side, it's a little more complicated, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: Thanks, yes I want to use it inside pagetoload.html