# Jquery code to split the href link

Tags: jquery

I have an href link as follows.i have to spilt `name` value and `id` value separately.

```
index.html?names=priya@gmail.com&id=68
```

Using jquery how can i split `priya@gmail.com` and `68`
i tried the following one

`var val =location.href.split('?')[1]`
which outputs the `priya@gmail.com&id=68`

i have to output `priya@gmail.com and 68` separately..how it is possible..

Comment: Check this [post][1]. It has different ways of doing it.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: Use `Regex`, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str="priya@gmail.com&id=68";

var emailrogh= str.split("&");

email=emailrogh[0];// show priya@gmail.com

var idrough=emailrogh[1].split("=");

var id=idrough[1];//show 68
```

**update**

```
var str="name=priya@gmail.com&id=68";

str=str.split("name=")[1];

var emailrogh= str.split("&");

email=emailrogh[0];// show priya@gmail.com

var idrough=emailrogh[1].split("=");

var id=idrough[1];//show 68
```

Comment: var str="names=priya@gmail.com&id=68"; var str contains names also .it is not working

Answer (score 1):

may be:

```
var str = "priya@gmail.com&id=68";
var splitted = str.replace("id=", "").split("&");
console.log( splitted );
//gives ["priya@gmail.com", "68"]
```

Answer (score 1):

use this function

```
function getParameterByName(name) 
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

this function will return your value directly.

for eg. for your link

```
index.html?names=priya@gmail.com&id=68
```

use this function as

```
var email = getParameterByName("names");
var id = getParameterByName("id");
```

values would be

```
email = "priya@gmail.com";
id = "68";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```