# get value from url parameter to replace html 5 data attribute

Tags: jquery, html, url, attributes

I've this div:

```
<div id="accordion-63-52453407315c8" 
     class="wk-accordion wk-accordion-default clearfix"  
     data-widgetkit="accordion"
     data-options='{"style":"default", 
                    "collapseall":1, 
                    "matchheight":0, 
                    "index":-1, 
                    "duration":500, 
                    "width":"auto", 
                    "order":"default"}'>
```

How I could change  index value in data-option attribute, from a parameter get by url string using Jquery code?

```
www.myurl.com?index=4
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get URL parameter with JavaScript or jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's approach this problem with the following two steps:

1. We need to retrieve the index from the url.
2. We need to update the value in the `data-options` attribute.

Let's do those now.

**Get the Index:**

```
var url = window.location.href;
var index = null;
if(url.lastIndexOf('?') != -1) {
    index = url.split('?')[1];
    index= index.split('=')[1];
}
```

**Modify the `data` attribute:**

```
var $accordian = $('#accordion-63-52453407315c8');
var obj = $accordian.data("options");
obj.index = parseInt(index);
$accordian.data("options", obj);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/8gL4b/) is a fiddle demonstrating how this works.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var obj = $("#accordion-63-52453407315c8").data("option");
var index = obj.index;
```

Comment: by far the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/Yutwc/)

Try this

Add this to your head for getting the query string

```
 <script src='https://rawgithub.com/allmarkedup/purl/master/purl.js'>
 </script>
```

and the code is

```
 var index1=$.url('http://www.myurl.com?index=4').param('index');
    $('#accordion-63-52453407315c8').data('options').index=index1; //assigning value to the index
```

if you want to get the parameter from the current url

```
 var index1=$.url(window.location.href).param('index');
 $('#accordion-63-52453407315c8').data('options').index=index1;
```