# How to show content only on permalink pages that have a question mark symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, meta-tags

```
<meta content='noindex' name='robots'/>
<meta content='noarchive' name='robots'/>
<meta content='nofollow' name='robots'/>
```

On pages `<head>`, How to show meta tags above **only** on permalink pages that have a question mark symbol (**?**).

Example permalink:

- `http://mydomain/blablahhblaa` (will **appear** on this permalink page
  `<head>`)
- `http://mydomain/blablahh?bla` (will **not Appear** on this permalink page
  `<head>`)

*INFO 1*: Platform: Blogger/Blogspot

*INFO 2*:By Default on Blogspot blog platform, to show/hide  content in certain permalink, just use code below:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;http://THEPERMALINK.COM/BLABLA&quot;'>

Content at this space will appear at this permalink http://THEPERMALINK.COM/BLABLA

<b:else/>

Content at this space will appear at all pages exclude this permalink http://THEPERMALINK.COM/BLABLA

</b:if>
```

*INFO 3*: And to get current URL in Blogspot blog platform, is using this code: `data:blog.url` or `<data:blog.url/>`

The point here: i want to try do something like below `Shortcut_For_Any_Permalink_Have_a_Question_Mark`

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;Shortcut_For_Any_Permalink_Have_a_Question_Mark&quot;'>
<meta content='noindex' name='robots'/>
<meta content='noarchive' name='robots'/>
<meta content='nofollow' name='robots'/>
</b:if>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This should be a server-side task, shouldn't it?

Comment: Are you using a server site scripting program like PHP?

Comment: if not take a look at this question (and its answer) on how to get url parameters with javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: @gillytech : No.. Blogger platform.

Comment: @Jason P : Blogger platform.

Comment: You mean "Blogger" the Google service?

Comment: @user1620427 Hiding markup with javascript won't have an effect on robots, will it?

Comment: @gillytech : Yes. Blogspot/Google service :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I would say that you should use your javascript to check if there are any URL parameters set (anything after the question mark) like this:

Note: This is untested and probably nonworking code. This is just to illustrate the concept.

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}

// example.com?param1=name
var param = $.urlParam('param1'); // name

if (param)
{
    // execute code
}
```

Then you can have JS write the meta lines in if there are any parameters set.

So by default there are no robots meta tags, and the JS will write them into the head tag if any parameters set.

Comment: Thanks @gillytech !!

And how to combine/convert it with code `<b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;Short_cut_For_Permalink_Have_a_QuestionMark&quot;'>` ?

Comment: i have edited this Question, how to combine/convert it with code `<b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;Shortcut_For_Any_Permalink_Have_a_Question_Mark&quot;'>`