# extract multiple parameters from a string & do something

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to extract multiple "parameters" from a string and for each parameter do something

e.g. If it detect `myParam1=xxx`, or `myParam2=yyy` etc.

In this code only one parameter can be detected, but I need multiple parameters:

```
function GetParameter(PPParam) {
    var input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
    var XXX = input1.value;

    var ZZZ = XXX.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < ZZZ.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = ZZZ[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == PPParam) {

            alert(sParameterName[1]);

            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/Qmu5L/1/**

**Note:** I need all the parameters will control a unique element,

for example to style a `<div>` (`width=100`, `color=red`, etc.)

---

[escaped URL parameters statements if else switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562330/escaped-url-parameters-statements-if-else-switch)

Comment: i found this in another place, i just trying to understand how to modify it but it just a bit hard for me... can you show a little example pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go -- I've updated your Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Qmu5L/3/ based on Stratus3D's suggestion. It will produce a hash of all the parameters and their values.

I suggest you look at jQuery if you want to start applyinmg styles and messing with CSS -- makes it a lot easier.

```
function getParameters() {
  var searchString = document.getElementById('input1').value,
      params = searchString.split("&"),
      hash = {};

  if (searchString == "") return {};
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var val = params[i].split("=");
    hash[unescape(val[0])] = unescape(val[1]);
  }
  console.log(hash);
  return hash;
}
```

Once you've got the hash you can simply run it though a JQuery `$.each` function to style your DIV.

Comment: @user3602937 If this answer solves your original question please mark it as accepted. If you now have an additional question please search stackoverflow and see if your question has already been answered. If not please ask a separate question.

Comment: ok how have i to start the new question: style a div using escaped URL parameters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549478/style-a-div-using-escaped-url-parameters

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562330/escaped-url-parameters-statements-if-else-switch

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of the function defined in this answer would work:

[Get escaped URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-escaped-url-parameter/8913606#8913606)

You would just need to remove the unescape calls and replace the reference to `window.location.search.substring` with string parameter you want to process.

Comment: i am new in javascript, i tried to follow your advices but i cant make it working...

Comment: Or if you're using jQuery, try the excellent URL Parser Plugin: https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser