# style a div using escaped URL parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm new in javascript and i don't exactly understand how to modify this code to style a div:

```
function getParameters() {
  var searchString = document.getElementById('input1').value,
      params = searchString.split("&"),
      hash = {};

  if (searchString == "") return {};
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var val = params[i].split("=");
    hash[unescape(val[0])] = unescape(val[1]);
  }
    console.log(hash);
  //return hash;
    $.each(hash, function( color, background ) {
      document.body.innerHTML += color + background ;
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qmu5L/4/

---

Have a look also here: [escaped URL parameters statements if else switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562330/escaped-url-parameters-statements-if-else-switch)

Comment: what do you mean by `style a div`

Comment: you can use `$(body).css('color',color)`. Take a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variables in the `.each(function(){});` function are not custom, they are always id and value.

your function should go like this:

```
$.each(hash, function (id, value) {
    test_div.style[id] = value;
});
```

here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/Qmu5L/5/)

whats going on basically is, that your hash array contains two objects:

1)  color {value = "red"}

2)  background {value = "yellow}

the each function iterates thought those, the `id` will be first time `color` ad second time `background`

and the value will be first time `"red"` ad second time `"yellow"`

so for the first iteration for example,  id = 'color' and value ='red' and it will produce:

```
test_div.style["color"] = "red";
```

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562330/escaped-url-parameters-statements-if-else-switch

Answer (score 0):

With the javascript function styleDiv you can pass the url string of style (style=value) and the targets (DOM element tag name, id, class). It will find those targets, and set styles.

Kudos to Banana for using element.style[property] = value, i didn't know about it.

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/chepe263/E2La3/2/)

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Style a Div</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js'></script>


  <style type='text/css'>
    input[type=text] {width: 300px;}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
styleDiv = function(paramString, target){
    param = paramString.split('&');
    if (param.length < 1)
        return false;
    for(i=0; i< param.length; i++){
        val = param[i].split('=');
        //jQuery(target).css(unescape(val[0]),unescape(val[1]));
        targets=document.querySelectorAll(target);
        for (t=0; t < targets.length; t++){
            targets[t].style[unescape(val[0])] = unescape(val[1]);
        }
    }
}

jQuery('#cmdSetStyle').click(function(e){
    console.log(styleDiv(jQuery('#txtParamStyle').val(),'#target'));
    return false;    
});

});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <form id="frmSendStyle" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="txtParamStyle" value="color=red&background=yellow" />
    <input type="button" id="cmdSetStyle" value="Set Style" />
</form>

<div id="target">
    Hello world
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: have look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562330/escaped-url-parameters-statements-if-else-switch