# escaped URL parameters statements if else switch

Tags: javascript

There is a little problem with this code:

```
function getParameters() {
  var searchString = document.getElementById('input1').value,
      params = searchString.split("&"),
      hash = {};

  if (searchString == "") return {};
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var val = params[i].split("=");
    hash[unescape(val[0])] = unescape(val[1]);
  }
    console.log(hash);
  //return hash;

  if(val[0] == "class"){ //alert(val[1]); 
    $.each(hash, function( attribute, value ) {
      test_div.setAttribute(attribute,value);
    });
  }
  else if(val[0] == "color"){ //alert(val[1]); 
    $.each(hash, function( attribute, value ) {
      test_div.style[attribute]=value;
    });
  }


  monitor_test_div.innerText = ccc.innerHTML;  
}
```

Depending by the order in which the parameters are inserted, they are repeated or dont work...

[style a div using escaped URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549478/style-a-div-using-escaped-url-parameters)

**Demo: [JSFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/36w7C/)**

**Demo: [JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/L8nxc/1/)**

I would like to obtain this:

---

**Example 1:**

input:

`opacity=0&src=link1&color=red&color=green&src=link2&height=200`

output:

```
 <div src="link2" style="color: green;"></div>
```

---

**Example 2:**

input:

`src=link1&color=red` or `color=red&src=link1`

output:

```
 <div src="link1" style="color: red;"></div>
```

---

Comment: What do you expect the val[0] in 'if if(val[0]...' to contain? It'll be the key of the last url parameter...

Comment: I'm sorry also for my language, it is a bit hard for me because i am new in javascript & html.. However i'll quickly accept your answer, sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your line

```
if(val[0] == "class")
```

you are only checking the first element in your val array.

what you would want to do, is iterate through all the hash objects and simply check the attribute like this:

```
function getParameters() {
  var searchString = document.getElementById('input1').value,
      params = searchString.split("&"),
      hash = {};

  if (searchString == "") return {};
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var val = params[i].split("=");
    hash[unescape(val[0])] = unescape(val[1]);
  }
    console.log(hash);
  //return hash;
    $.each(hash, function( attribute, value ) {

        if(attribute=="color"){
            test_div.style[attribute]=value;
        }
        else if(attribute=="src"){
            alert(attribute);
            test_div.setAttribute(attribute,value);
        }
    });
}
```

here is a working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/Dz9e4/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
var test_div = $('#test_divs_id');

for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
 var val = params[i].split("=");

 var key = unescape(val[0]);
 var val = unescape(val[1]);

 switch(key) {

  case 'class':            // treat 'class' key by ...
   test_div.addClass(val); // ... adding the value as a class
   break;

  case 'src':              // treat 'src' key,
  case 'href':             // treat 'href' key, maybe more ...
   test_div.attr(key, val); //... by adding as an attribute with value
   break;

  default:                 // all other keys...
   test_div.css(key, val); // ... are assumed css style names with value
   break;
 }
```

EDIT: Extended the switch with the examples + possibly more attributes

Comment: I'm new in javascript guys, please can you show some example?

Comment: Could you please add an example to your question of what input you expect to produce what output.