# How to pass a variable to a new page and insert it to a textbox?

Tags: javascript, variables, popup

I am trying to transfer a variable from one page using this code:

```
<a href="login.html" onclick="NameFunction('asdf');">Edit</a>
```

to the page `login.html`, and insert the variable(`asdf` in this example) to a `textbox` in the new page.

I have tried this code:

```
function NameFunction(name) {
    document.getElementById("username").value = name;
}
```

It is not working. I think it doesn't work because thats another page.

Comment: What do you mean "it's another page"? Please show your complete html document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass parameters to another page you can put them using query string:

```
<a href="login.html?param=asdf">Edit</a>
```

To get parameter on the `login.html` page you can use jQuery as it described here: [Get escaped URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-escaped-url-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

you can try using localStorage.

1. In you're onClick method, save the data you want to store in localStorage

   localStorage.setItem(key,value);
2. When the new page loads, in the onLoad (ready function if using jquery) method get the data from localStorage and set it in the textbox

you can find more about localStorage in the following links

[Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

and many more are available online